# Python: Create subplots with plots generated by a "class"

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, subplot

I know what I want to do but I'm not sure how to make this question.

In my code I'm using *lightkurve* package, which has a class (*lightkurve.lightcurve.TessLightCurve*) that has a method (plot) that plots the content of a variable.
The "plot" method uses matplotlib.

In this way, I'm able to plot two independent figures like the following:

```
curve.plot()
plt.title("Merged unnormalized light curve \n nº of sectors merged: {0}".format(len(tpfs)))

corrected_curve.plot()
plt.title("Merged NORMALIZED light curve \n nº of sectors merged: {0}".format(len(tpfs)))
```

That give me the following figures:

[image: Figure 1]
[image: Figure 2]

What I want to do is to have a single plot with those two figures as subplots.
I know how to do it with typical plots and subplots like the ones described in the [matplotlib page](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html), but I've no idea how to do it with this type of figures :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the function `lightkurve.lightcurve.TessLightCurve.plot()` [takes an argument `ax=`](https://docs.lightkurve.org/api/lightkurve.lightcurve.TessLightCurve.html#lightkurve.lightcurve.TessLightCurve.plot) to instruct which subplot to use.

```py
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1)
curve.plot(ax=ax1)
ax1.set_title("Merged unnormalized light curve \n nº of sectors merged: {0}".format(len(tpfs)))

corrected_curve.plot(ax=ax2)
ax2.set_title("Merged NORMALIZED light curve \n nº of sectors merged: {0}".format(len(tpfs)))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Diziet! You guys make it so easy.
I will have a look in detail in order to assimilate it and learn for the next time.

Thank you! :)